# How to prove no integer solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

What I want to do is prove that there are no integers x, y that satisfy this equation:

$11=x^2-3y^2$

I tried solving and other methods, but to no avail. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: You can use a solution like the one of user4140, working modulo $3$ instead. It is not hard to check that any square is congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$. But $3y^2$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $3$, so $x^2-3y^2$ is congruent to $x^2$. And $11$ is congruent to $2$, but no square can be. The proof modulo $4$ is in some sense "better", since one ends up using congruences mod $4$ more often than congruences mod $3$.

Answer (score 6):

11 is congruent to 3 mod 4. While squares are only congruent 0 and 1 mod 4. Therefore $x^2-3y^2$ can only be $1-3,0-3,1-0$or $0-0$ So it can't be.

---

Proof squares are only conguent 1 and 0:

if k is even then $k=2m\rightarrow k^2=(2m)^2=4m^2$

if k is odd then $k=2m+1 \rightarrow k^2=(2m+1)^2=4m^2+4m+1=4(m^2+m)+1$